# How to read date from plist and assign it to datepicker?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, nsdate

I have a plist file with Title and Message keys.

I want to add date to plist. like this :

[image]

I managed to NSLog the date :

[image]

The application crashed when I try to assign date from plist to datepicker.

```
self.userDate = [temp objectForKey:@"Date"];
myDate.date = userDate;
```

How to read date from plist and assign it to datepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that userDate is not a NSDate object, it's probably a string. You should use a NSDateFormatter and it's dateFromString method to turn it into a NSDate object.

```
self.userDate = [temp objectForKey:@"Date"];
myDate.date = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] dateFromString:userDate];
```